# Mocking file uploads in Rails 3.1 controller tests

Tags: file-upload, mocking, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec-rails

My controller accesses the `tempfile` attribute of an uploaded file and passes it to another mocked component. My test code has

```
  @file = mock(Object)
  @file.stub_chain(:tempfile, :path).and_return('thefile.zip')
  # ...
  post :create, :file => @file
```

and the controller code calls `params[:file].tempfile.path`.

After upgrading from Rails 3.0 to 3.1, the above line started failing with

```
undefined method `tempfile' for "#[RSpec::Mocks::Mock:0x2b0d9a0 @name=Object]":String
```

That is, Rails 3.1 converted `params[:file]` to a string automatically.

The code works properly when tested manually through a browser. I tried to use `fixture_file_upload` and the parameter became a `File` object but it had no `tempfile` method.

So how do I pass an arbitrary mock object as a parameter to an action in Rails 3.1?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally found [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.rails/297939), which tells that although the thing returned by `fixture_file_upload` has a `@tempfile` member, it lacks the reader method. Solved as follows

```
  FileUtils.touch('file.zip') # fixture_file_upload needs the file to exist
  @file = fixture_file_upload('file.zip')
  class << @file
    # The reader method is present in a real invocation,
    # but missing from the fixture object for some reason (Rails 3.1.1)
    attr_reader :tempfile
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

I went around this way

```
upload_file = fixture_file_upload('files/stats_upload.csv', 'text/csv')
upload_file.stubs(:tempfile).returns(upload_file)
```

Comment: In order to use this you will need to add `gem 'mocha'` to your `Gemfile`.

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `stubs' for #<Tempfile

Answer (score 0):

I made a pull request to fix this issue, please +1 if you like it: https://github.com/brynary/rack-test/pull/67

Comment: Your pull seems to have been merged, but as of Rails 3.2.13rc2, with rack-test 0.6.2, I still had to use @mpartel's workaround above

Comment: any chance of getting a release that includes this fix?