# File upload testing using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, specifications

How do I generate a file for testing with a given size and test file upload in rspec?  I want to generate the file.

I currently have the files in fixtures/files and use fixture_file_upload as a test file.  I want to eliminate the need for that sample file.

Answer (score 3):

You could use  [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) or [fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) to mock the uploaded file.

A sample configuration for `factory_girl` would look like:

```
factory :attachment do
  supporting_documentation_file_name { 'test.pdf' }
  supporting_documentation_content_type { 'application/pdf' }
  supporting_documentation_file_size { 1024 }
end
```

Take a look in this nice article on why and how to [do that using factory girl](http://pivotallabs.com/avoid-using-fixture-file-upload-with-factorygirl-and-paperclip/)

This, as the article describes, requires a shift in your testing philosophy. Instead of testing the file uploading itself (which the gem you are using is already testing for you) you just focus on the necessary models.

An alternative to exercise the actual uploading can be found here [Mocking file uploads in Rails 3.1 controller tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793510/mocking-file-uploads-in-rails-3-1-controller-tests)

Comment: So by this we don't need any actual file at all??

Comment: @PiKaY fixture_file_upload does need the actual file, the alternative suggested by the provided article does not. See my updated answer for some clarification on what you are actually testing

Answer (score -1):

If someone wants to stub uploaded file to test model logic, here is the solution:

```
    file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'images', 'test-file.jpg'), 'image/jpg')

    allow_any_instance_of(Model).to receive(:photo_obj).and_return file
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to eliminate the need for a sample file.